# Select from base on same value on another column

Tags: mysql

I need to select all row from same `customer_id` given `visit_id` in one mysql query.

**Example data**

| visit_id | customer_id | time | point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1624293577 | 22 |
| 2 | 1 | 1724293577 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 | 1824293577 | 14 |
| 4 | 3 | 1924293577 | 85 |
| 5 | 2 | 1974293577 | 41 |
| 6 | 1 | 2024293577 | 23 |

**Desired results**

if I give visit_id = 1 if should return all row from customer equal 1

| visit_id | customer_id | time | point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1624293577 | 22 |
| 2 | 1 | 1724293577 | 12 |
| 6 | 1 | 2024293577 | 23 |

I can achieve this by running mysql query 2 times.
First get `customer_id` from selected `visit_id`,
then get all row that had `customer_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just have a subquery in a where clause as joining the table to itself will likely cause duplicate rows

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  yourTable
WHERE
  customer_id = (SELECT customer_id FROM yourTable WHERE visit_id = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with itself.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
WHERE t2.visit_id = 1
```